# XSL key lookup in second file & replace element

Tags: attributes, key, match, xslt-2.0

I have two xml files:

Source.xml

```
<osm>
  <count>
    <tag k="total" v="1560"/>
  </count>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="111111"/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="222222"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="XXX XXX"/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="333333"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="YYY YYY"/>
  </node>
  <way>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="444444"/>
  </way>
  <way>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="555555"/>
    <tag  v="ZZZ ZZZ"/>
  </way>
</osm>
```

Lookup.xml

```
<FHRSEstablishment>
    <EstablishmentCollection>
        <EstablishmentDetail>
            <FHRSID>111111</FHRSID>
            <PostCode>BA1 111</PostCode>
        </EstablishmentDetail>
        <EstablishmentDetail>
            <FHRSID>333333</FHRSID>
            <PostCode>BA2 222</PostCode>
        </EstablishmentDetail>
        <EstablishmentDetail>
            <FHRSID>555555</FHRSID>
            <PostCode>BA3 333</PostCode>
        </EstablishmentDetail>
    </EstablishmentCollection>
</FHRSEstablishment>
```

I wish to compare them using the corresponding `@v` value of the `k=fhrs:id` attribute in source.xml with the `FHRSID` node value in lookup.xml to produce an amended version of source.xml.

When a match is found, the value of the `Postcode` node should be copied across to replace the value of the `@v` attribute for the tag element with the attribute `k="addr:postcode"`.

This is the XSL fille:

```
<xsl:key name="FHRSID-key" match="FHRSID" use="node()"/>
<xsl:variable name="lookup-doc" select="doc('lookup.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/tag[@v and key('FHRSID-key', @v, $lookup-doc)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="k">addr:postcode</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="v" select="key('FHRSID-key', @v, $lookup-doc)/../PostCode/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the current output

```
<osm>
   <count>
      <tag k="total" v="1560"/>
   </count>
   <node>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA1 111"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="222222"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="XXX XXX"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA2 222"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="YYY YYY"/>
   </node>
   <way>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="444444"/>
   </way>
   <way>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA3 333"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="ZZZ ZZZ"/>
   </way>
</osm>
```

This is the desired ouput:

```
<osm>
    <count>
    <tag k="total" v="1560"/>
    </count>
    <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="111111"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA1 111"/>
    </node>
    <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="222222"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="XXX XXX"/>
    </node>
    <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="333333"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA2 222"/>
  </node>
  <way>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="444444"/>
  </way>
  <way>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="555555"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA3 333"/>
  </way>
</osm>
```

As you can see it's replacing the `'fhrs:id'` element with the copied postcode element, instead of the original `k="addr:postcode"`.

Incidental questions:

```
match="*/tag[@v and key('FHRSID-key', @v, $lookup-doc)]"
```

Is the first occurrence of `@v` actually doing anything?

To me, this match appears to be searching all tag elements. If so, how can it be restricted to look just for those with just the  `k="addr:postcode"` attribute.

Any other improvements to be recommended, please feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the code to match on the parent

```
<xsl:key name="FHRSID-key" match="EstablishmentDetail" use="FHRSID"/>
<xsl:variable name="lookup-doc" select="doc('lookup.xml')"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[tag[@k = 'fhrs:id' and key('FHRSID-key', @v, $lookup-doc)]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node() except tag[@k = 'addr:postcode']"/>
        <tag k="addr:postcode" v="{key('FHRSID-key', tag[@k = 'fhrs:id']/@v, $lookup-doc)/PostCode}"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

gives

```
<osm>
   <count>
      <tag k="total" v="1560"/>
   </count>
   <node>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="111111"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA1 111"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="222222"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="XXX XXX"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="333333"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA2 222"/>
   </node>
   <way>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="444444"/>
   </way>
   <way>
      <tag k="fhrs:id" v="555555"/>
      <tag v="ZZZ ZZZ"/>
      <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA3 333"/>
   </way>
</osm>
```

where the only problem seems to be the `<tag v="ZZZ ZZZ"/>` element. I am not sure which are the criteria to copy or not copy existing content, if you only want to keep the `tag k="fhrs:id"` then change that last template to

```
<xsl:template match="*[tag[@k = 'fhrs:id' and key('FHRSID-key', @v, $lookup-doc)]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , tag[@k = 'fhrs:id']"/>
        <tag k="addr:postcode" v="{key('FHRSID-key', tag[@k = 'fhrs:id']/@v, $lookup-doc)/PostCode}"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```